# Why is my navigation list reversed?

Tags: html, css

So I've run into this problem a few times, how come my navigation menu is reversed?

```css
.navigation li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

When put into action, the menu order is reversed, why is this happening?
[image]

Comment: you floated right. that means the first element goes to the right edge, then the second elements goes to the left of that first element, blah blah blah

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? There are built-in styles for right-aligning menus: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment

Answer (score 7):

You let the elements *float* to the right. Try to picture that..

The first element enters the document and floats all the way to the right, bumping into the side of the screen. The second enters and floats to the right as well, but bumps into the left side of the first, and stays there. And so on, and so on.

A better solution would be to use `display: inline-block` for the elements, and `float-right` for the parent (the `ul`).

But personally I'm not a big fan of floating at all, so I would use `text-align` on the `ul`. `text-align` keeps it a normal line of text, which can also include images or other inline and inline-block elements. By right-aligning the text, the order of the words is not changed, but any remaining white space is just added to the left instead of to the right of the line:

```css
.navigation li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation ul {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
```

Comment: Ah you legend! So I used `float: right` on the ul, and the `display: inline-block` on the `.navigation li`  instead of `.navigation li a`

Comment: Or not use float: right at all. See my code sample. Whichever *floats* your boat (pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because **that's how `float` was designed.** It will "float" the elements in the *direction* specified, in the *order* specified. If order is important, you can fix this in three ways:

1. Use the [built-in Bootstrap alignment tools](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment).
2. Apply `float: right` to the parent `<ul>` rather than each link.
3. Reverse the order of the elements.

In this case, you are floating elements to the **right**, in the order `About > Portfolio > Contact`. This is what happens:

1. `About` is floated right with no previous elements, so it sits against the farthest right wall of the parent container, `<ul>`.
2. `Portfolio` is floated right, but `About` is there already, so it gets as far right as it can, which puts it to the **left** of the previous element.
3. `Contact` is last to the party, so it ends up at the end of the line, farthest left.